# Query Optimization - typical to scenario

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query which takes like 11 seconds to fetch the record because the database is huge like 150mb. (**EDITED**: Sorry this is not huge, people let me realized me :D )

**How to optimize this query?**

```
select id, post_title,featured, location, application_deadline, post_name, post_content, post_date as d, logo FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
  WHERE wp_posts.post_status='publish' 
        AND wp_posts.post_type='post' 
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
        AND wp_terms.post_type='news' 
        order by post_date desc limit 0, 9
```

Comment: 150mb is not considered huge, it's actually quite small. You are probably missing indexes on your join fields.

Answer (score 1):

First of all 150 mb is not huge. I would recommend using the Execution plans in SSMS to identify where the query is under performing.

[image]

You can use the Estimated and actual plans.

Heres a good article if you don't know anything about execution plans:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link. It's helpful not only for my solution but countless 
 stuff.

Comment: Happy to help! Table Indexes will also help.

Comment: Yes that indexes has significantly reduced loading time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

1. Converted all tables to INNODB
2. Added primary key where required
3. Indexed relational columns 
   Time reduced from 11 sec to 0.3 sec.